# Quarkus Extension - write fields annotated with a custom annotation

Tags: java, quarkus

At our company we are trying to migrate some of our applications from `J2EE to Quarkus`.

For the J2EE apps we have a `proprietary framework` that performs dependency injection based on custom annotations applied on a field. We have a `CDI extension` in which we override the beans `InjectionTarget` and at bean's instantiation time we set, through reflection, the field value based on the annotation present, like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBean {

    @CustomAnnotation
    private String myField; // injected by our framework
```

We would like to migrate our applications keeping this behaviour. Is there any way to do this `with Quarkus`? We have seen that with Quarkus extensions we can transform the qualifiers of an injection point, like this:

```
@BuildStep
InjectionPointTransformerBuildItem transformPropertyAnnotation(final BeanArchiveIndexBuildItem beanArchiveIndex) {
    return new InjectionPointTransformerBuildItem(new InjectionPointsTransformer() {
        public void transform(TransformationContext context) {
            // do my transformations
        }
    }
}
```

But we didn't find a way to "enhance" how a field is being initialized, even with Quarkus recorders.

Comment: Have you had a look at `io.quarkus.arc.deployment.AnnotationsTransformerBuildItem`?

Comment: Yes. If I'm not missing something, with that build item you can remove/add annotations. Instead we would like to basically intercept the bean instantiation, much like we do by [wrapping the injection target](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#_wrapping_an_injectiontarget) with the old CDI

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to intercept the bean instantiation

Comment: Ok, we'll work around this. Thank you anyway